# Mvc Donut Caching disable caching programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, donut-caching

I'm using [MvcDonutCaching](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3) on my project and looking for a way to disable caching globally to assist during debugging/testing.

I can't find any examples on how to achieve this in the documentation though I did find the `CacheSettingsManager` which exposes a `IsCachingEnabledGlobally` property however this is `readonly`.

The `CacheSettingsManager` doesn't have any constructors which would allow me to configure this setting either. Is there a way of configuring this setting?

There is an alternative solution which may work (ugly) but it's an absolute last resort and shouldn't really be necessary:

```
public class CustomOutputCache : DonutOutputCacheAttribute
{
    public CustomOutputCache()
    {
        if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseCache"] == "false")
        {
            base.NoStore = true;
            base.Duration = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And then using this on my controller actions:

```
[CustomOutputCache]
public ActionResult Homepage() 
{
    // etc...
}
```

Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is an ugly solution, but you could consider the use of compilation flags. Something like:

```
#if !DEBUG
[DonutOutputCache]
#endif      
public ActionResult Homepage() 
{
   // etc...
}
```

This will compile the attribute only when non-Debug configurations are selected.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this, add the below in your FilterConfig.cs

```
public class AuthenticatedOnServerCacheAttribute : DonutOutputCacheAttribute
{
    private OutputCacheLocation? originalLocation;

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        //NO CACHING this way
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseCache"] == "false")
        {
            originalLocation = originalLocation ?? Location;
            Location = OutputCacheLocation.None;
        }
        //Caching is on
        else
        {
            Location = originalLocation ?? Location;
        }

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

You can now add this to your controllers.

```
    [AuthenticatedOnServerCache(CacheProfile = "Cache1Day")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This answer was inspired by [Felipe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97082/felipe-fujiy-pessoto) answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9694955/1911240